# Verify if mysql command executed

Tags: c#, mysql

I am using

```
public static bool command(string input, MySqlConnection con)
{
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(input, con);
    var resultSet = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (!resultSet.Equals(0))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

With as an example:

```
bool comm = mysql_command.command("INSERT INTO sometable (field1,field2) VALUES ('val1','val2')", connection);
if (!comm) textBox1.Text += "Command failed";
else textBox1.Text += "Command successful";
```

Which correctly adds `Command successful` to textbox1.

But when I change `sometable` to `sometablee`, textbox1 stays empty. I was expecting it to notify me the command failed (`sometablee` does not exist), but it didn't.

Can anyone tell me why?

**Full code:**

mysql_command:

```
class mysql_command
{
    public static bool command(string input, MySqlConnection con)
    {
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(input, con);
        var resultSet = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (!resultSet.Equals(0))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

mysql_connect:

```
class mysql_connect
{
    private MySqlConnection connection = null;

    public MySqlConnection connect(string server, string database, string UID, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            string MyConString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" +
                "DATABASE=" + database + ";" +
                "UID=" + UID + ";" +
                "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
            connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
            connection.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine("MySQL connect error : "+ex.Message); }
        return connection;
    }

    public void disconnect()
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mysql_connect con = new mysql_connect();
    MySqlConnection connection = con.connect("server1.x.x", "somedb", "user", "pass");

    bool comm = mysql_command.command("INSERT INTO sometable (field1,field2) VALUES ('val1','val1')", connection);
    if (!comm) textBox1.Text += "Command failed";
    else textBox1.Text += "Command successful";
}
```

Comment: Would you post your full code, I think you will get an exception and ...

Comment: Also - you are leaking memory in the `MySqlCommand` local variable, use `using` for anything that is `IDisposable`

Comment: @SaeedAmiri I added the full code.

Comment: @SteveTownsend I was under the impression that garbage collection automatically does this for me.. is this not the case? From MSDN : `C#, through the .NET Framework common language runtime (CLR), automatically releases the memory used to store objects that are no longer required. The release of memory is non-deterministic; memory is released whenever the CLR decides to perform garbage collection. However, it is usually best to release limited resources such as file handles and network connections as quickly as possible.`

Comment: GC will do that but only when it decides it is time to.  For things that map to unmanaged resources, you are supposed to call `IDisposable.Dispose` to ensure timely cleanup of eg. file handles, sockets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is as I expected, you will get an exception in your command method,

```
public static bool command(string input, MySqlConnection con)
```

because requested table is not exists, ....
Edit your command method to handle exception:

```
public static bool command(string input, MySqlConnection con)
{
    try
    {
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(input, con);
    var resultSet = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (!resultSet.Equals(0))
        return true;
    return false;
    }
    catch
    {}
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! I was expecting my program to crash if it was something like that, since I didn't add a try/catch in there... how come it didn't?

Comment: May be you catch it in higher level.

Comment: Don't think so, `Form1_Load` is using the `command()` function directly, and there's no try/catch in there either.. strange.

Comment: Wow swallowing the exception like that is not dumb at all!!